how to capture a ball in cloth?
as in, so the ball falls into the cloth that's lying on a torus, then gets captured in it.
I've tried soft body and rigid body, neither worked with collisions or not. i don't really have any further ideas.

Did you set the cloth collision collection?

i have tried to set the ball's collection, i dont know of the cloth's collection though
